# Drywall Comes With Two Sheets Taped Together for Shipping - Proper Way to Tear It Off

Tags: drywall

I am completely new to drywall (working on my own house) and learning what I can before I get started. Drywall is sold in sets of two.  Each sheet faces the other and the ends are taped together with paper tape.  When I pull this paper off, I take off the drywall paper.  Is there a proper technique for removing the shipping paper - the paper that hold the two sheets together?

Answer (score 9):

It's common to just slice that tape with the same knife you'd use to score the panels to break them down when smaller pieces are needed. A bit of tape left on the panel's back is harmless.

Answer (score 6):

Just grab one end of the cardboard piece under the paper and pull. It may take a while to get the hang of it, but pulling it off the end and not to the side should not have any of the other paper rip other than the paper over the cardboard that you are pulling.

Comment: I know that's supposed to work, but I tend to be a bit paranoid about it, hence my suggestion to slice.  Try both and see which you like better?

Comment: I have opened up hundreds and hundreds of sheets over the years and years, that's the way I have always done it. That the way I have always seen the hangers of sheetrock do it. I actually pull about a half dozen about half way way across the end, collecting each one in the other and and pull all the remaining way all at once. I seen the pros do it that way, so I tried it a while back and been doing it that way ever since.... when there is enough to make it worthwhile doing it that way....

Comment: Good 'nuff for me.

Comment: If you feel like it, you can go to evil orange and practice ripping strips until they notice and throw you out.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate now that's funny... I don't care where you're from....

Comment: As a bonus, you grab about 5 at a time, then after 10-15 tie them in a knot so they don't litter the floor all over.